# Changing column type in pandas is not working when subsetting with iloc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I want to change the column type of a variable in a pandas data frame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]], columns = ["A", "B", "C"])
```

The following code is working

```
df["A"] = df["A"].astype("float64")
```

while this is not

```
df.iloc[:, 0] = df.iloc[:, 0].astype("float64")
```

Why?

Comment: Works for me, on Pandas 2.0.3 and 1.5.3, though I get a warning on 1.5.3. What version are you using?

Comment: Here's the warning if it helps: ``DeprecationWarning: In a future version, `df.iloc[:, i] = newvals` will attempt to set the values inplace instead of always setting a new array. To retain the old behavior, use either `df[df.columns[i]] = newvals` or, if columns are non-unique, `df.isetitem(i, newvals)` ``